# NoMethodError in RailsAdmin::MainController#dashboard undefined method `is_admin?' for #<User:0x007fc87c140c48> Did you mean? is_haml?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rails-admin

[Currently I'm using devise and rails_admin on Rails 5.0.0.1, when I open admin panel this error is showing up.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ipJX.png)

> After I added below lines in rails_admin.rb file for authorization, above error arises

```
config.authorize_with do
redirect_to main_app.root_path unless current_user.is_admin?
```

end

Comment: Give more details: 1) what you wanted 2) what you tried 3) what happened.

Comment: @Bikal, how do you differentiate a standard user from admin? Do you have an `admin` field or a `role` field in your `users` table?

Comment: @peterh, currently I have two users who can post, who both perform CRUD operations, now I want to assign any one user as admin. I tried assigning through rails console but it throws up errors.

Comment: @ArunKumar, did u mean 20160815102438_devise_create_users.rb file? If   so then, I have added   t.boolean :admin. I am quite new to rails, sorry if I didn't get you.

Comment: @Bikal, See my answer and let me know if it helps.

Comment: @Bikal, It works fine for me. I don't get any error when I try to access `http://localhost:3000/admin`. What error are you getting?

Comment: @ArunKumar, same as before.. NoMethodError in RailsAdmin::MainController#dashboard
undefined method `admin' for #<User:0x00000003f284d0>. The rails_admin authorization code is giving me the error but works fine when removed.

Comment: @Bikal, Strange. I don't get errors as you mention. I created a new user. In the rails console, I updated that user as ad admin. And when I tried to access `/admin`, I was able to get to the dashboard. One thing I wanted to tell was that you should modify your migration to set a default value of false for the  `admin` field.

Answer (score 0):

The error states that `is_admin?` method is not defined for a `user` instance. I assume you have an `admin` attribute in your model. You can either define the method in the model like

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 def is_admin?
   self.admin #returns a boolean
 end
 ...
end
```

Or replace the block with

```
config.authorize_with do
  redirect_to main_app.root_path unless current_user.admin
end
```

`current_user.admin` will return a boolean value based on the field `admin` in the `users` table.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same issue and was able to find a solution.

Add this to rails_admin.rb:

```
  config.authorize_with do
    redirect_to main_app.root_path unless current_user.admin?
  end
```

if you are working with devise add it underneath the devise section like so:

```
RailsAdmin.config do |config|

  ### Popular gems integration

  ## == Devise ==
  config.authenticate_with do
    warden.authenticate! scope: :user
  end
  config.current_user_method(&:current_user)

  config.authorize_with do
    redirect_to main_app.root_path unless current_user.admin?
  end
```